# Can I replace the null values with text for an outer join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to replace null from a query with some text, instead of having to do it via code.

The query is written as the following:

> mysql> SELECT title,  AVG(rating) AS avg_rating  FROM movie m LEFT
>   OUTER JOIN rating r ON m.movieID = r.movieID WHERE `year` < 1980 Group
>   BY title;

```
+-------------------------------------+------------+
| title                               | avg_rating |
+-------------------------------------+------------+
| Davy Crockett and the River Pirates |     3.6667 |
| Dumbo                               |     2.0000 |
| Fantasia                            |     1.5000 |
| Rocky                               |       NULL |
| Superman                            |       NULL |
| The Godfather                       |       NULL |
| The Jungle Book                     |     4.6667 |
+-------------------------------------+------------+
```

Instead of NULL, is it possible to have a text that says 'no rating'?

Comment: yes. But the datatype of the column will need to change to "text" (you cannot have a column that has strings in some rows and numbers in some rows)

Comment: @Strawberry that actually works! Strangely though using the MySQL workbench, it gives an output of "blob"

Comment: In that case even IFNULL would give the right solution, right?

Comment: Fdreger is mistaken, or has perhaps misunderstood the requirement. It should be unnecessary to CAST/CONVERT the integer type to text but maybe workbench needs that push. Either way, do not change the data type of the column!

Comment: @Strawberry: Perhaps you have misunderstood my comment? No matter how you approach the query (coalesce, when, you name it) - the result will be a column of strings, not of numbers. Which may be a problem. Or may not be a problem. Depends on what is done with the query results later on.

Comment: Yes, but the data type has no bearing on the matter - unless you want to UPDATE the column.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with the following query:

```
SELECT title,
COALESCE(AVG(rating),'NIL') AS avg_rating
FROM movie m LEFT OUTER JOIN rating r ON m.movieID = r.movieID
WHERE `year` < 1980
Group BY title
```

Credit : @Strawberry